# how to update an object using useEffect in Reactjs and Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-redux

I am very new to `Reactjs` + `Typescript` and i am trying to figure out why i am getting the error below.

`React 16.9`

```
const STEP_STATUS = {
  COMPLETED: "Completed",
  INCOMPLETE: "Incomplete",
};

const Foo = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    step: 1,
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    status: STEP_STATUS["INCOMPLETE"],
  });

const nextStep = () => {
    setState({...state, step: state.step + 1});
  }

useEffect(() => {
    if (state.step + 1 !== state.step) {
      // setState(prev => {...prev, state.step = STEP_STATUS["COMPLETED"]}); // I tried this too
      setState(...state, state.status = STEP_STATUS["COMPLETED"]);
    } else {
      console.log("error");  // don't mind this line
    }
  }, [state]);
```

I am trying to create a **side effect** using `useEffect`, after pressing the button `nextStep`(which brings the user to the next page), I want to update the status of current page to "Completed" before we get to the next page.

I might really be doing this wrong.

Any help would be very helpful.

## current error

```
×
TypeError: state is not iterable
  53 | useEffect(() => {
  54 |   if (state.step + 1 !== state.step) {
  55 |     // setState(prev => {...prev, state.step = STEP_STATUS["COMPLETED"]});
> 56 |     setState(...state, state.status = STEP_STATUS["COMPLETED"]);
     | ^  57 |   } else {
  58 |     console.log("error");
  59 |   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is a good idea to use the entire `state` as the dependency array on the `useEffect` hook. This will actually lead to an inifinite loop at the updating of `state` within the `useEffect` hook will result it to be triggered over and over again.

Looking at what you are trying to achieve, I believe `state.step` should be on the dependency array instead. In addition, you are using the wrong syntax for referencing properties within an object. Instead of using equal (`=`), you should be using the colon(`:`) instead.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setState({
    ...state,
    status: STEP_STATUS["COMPLETED"]
  });
}, [state.step]);
```

If you are trying to make use of the callback within `setState` instead, you can modify to this:

```
setState((prevState) => ({
  ...prevState,
  status: STEP_STATUS["COMPLETED"]
}));
```

Comment: good call thanks - do you know why its already update to `completed` after the rerender of the page. i am trying to update the status only when the button `nextStep` is pressed.

Comment: When is the `nextStep` method fired? I assume when the button is clicked?

Comment: correct, `nextStep` method is fired only after clicking the button, but currently when i look at the `console.log` the `status` is automatically updated to `completed` before i even press that button.

Comment: Did you set the dependency array on your `useEffect()` to this? `[state.step]`. As stated in my answer? In addition, is there something else in your code that is changing the value of `state.step`?

Comment: I did what you said...the `if` statement onthe first line, the logic is not correct, i tried to change it to `if (state.step > 1) {` to see the difference. Do you have any idea what that logic could be? i am referring to this line `if (state.step + 1 !== state.step) {`

Comment: Can you update your question with the button element?

Comment: I see that you have already accepted the answer, but I don't think there is a need for the if statement there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put object braces around the call of setState as follow:

```
setState({...state, status: STEP_STATUS["COMPLETED"]})
```

also it's recommended to update using the prevState values passed to setState in order to prevent clousers.

Comment: do you know why its already update to `completed` after the rerender of the page. i am trying to update the status only when the button `nextStep` is pressed.