# How to return an object conditionally

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, antd

I'm working on a web App project and I have the following component that is returned by antd `Menu` object.

```
const items = [
        {
          label: <Link to='/register'>Register</Link>,
          key: 'register',
          icon: <UserAddOutlined />,
          style: { marginLeft: 1030},   // problem: hard-coded margin
        },
        {
          label: <Link to='/login'>Login</Link>,
          key: 'login',
          icon: <UserOutlined />,
          style: { marginLeft: 'auto'},
        },               
      ];

return <Menu mode="horizontal" items={items} />;
```

Now I have an object named `user`. If `user` is not **null** (which means there is a user who is logged in currently), I want to hide `register` in the above `items` object; otherwise I want to show `register` in the `Menu`. The `Menu` component will be looked like:

[image]

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert this code after declaring `items`,

```
if(users!==null)
{
  items.splice(0,1) //removes first array element which is the register button
}
```

I would **highly** recommend you to use state for this purpose because that is the intended way for such cases.

By that I mean encapsulate the `items` object into a state and use the code above during every re-render using something like `useeffect` hook

Look at the question and the verified answer below to understand how to do it in newer versions of react

[how to update an object using useEffect in Reactjs and Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62111185/how-to-update-an-object-using-useeffect-in-reactjs-and-typescript)

Answer (score 1):

You just have to remember that `items` is a regular array. Not everything in React are exotic objects. A lot of your code will be using normal objects like strings, arrays, numbers etc. Don't be blinded by the array literal syntax that you forget that it's just an array.

There is already an answer showing what you can do to the `items` array to remove the first item. But you can also just write it simply:

```
let items = [];

if (user !== null) {
    items.push({
        label: <Link to='/register'>Register</Link>,
        key: 'register',
        icon: <UserAddOutlined />,
        style: { marginLeft: 1030},   // problem: hard-coded margin
    })
}

items.push({
    label: <Link to='/login'>Login</Link>,
    key: 'login',
    icon: <UserOutlined />,
    style: { marginLeft: 'auto'},
})

return <Menu mode="horizontal" items={items} />;
```